# does PHP support Downcasting?

Tags: php, laravel, oop, casting, downcast

i was searching in the internet for a way to do downcasting in PHP, but i couldn't find any thing useful, does PHP support it? if not, is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: @nice_dev https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downcasting

Comment: Cast operator does not accept class names. You cannot convert an object across classes.

Comment: There isn't a way in PHP, it throws an error as of now.

Comment: Regarding the "is there a way to achieve that" part, you basically need to create an instance of the target class and copy the properties you want. You can make it as ingenious as you want but it's basically a manual hack for an unsupported feature.